# Assembly: cause of segmentation fault

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault

I'm very new to `assembly language`, so i don't have that much knowledge. I was just trying to read some `message` from user, then output `"Hello, World!\n"` and then output `message` that user entered.

Here's what i basically do:

```
# TODO: Read message from input, output "Hello, World!", and output message on newline 

.section .data                  # Data that will be used by program


  ## * CONSTANTS * ##

  .equ LINUX_SYSCALL, 0x80      # Interrupt ID to make syscall on kernel (GNU/Linux)
  
  ## * SYCALL IDs * ##
  .equ EXIT_SYS, 1              # SYSCALL Number for exiting
  .equ OPEN_SYS, 5              # SYSCALL Number for opening files
  .equ READ_SYS, 3              # SYSCALL Number for reading from files
  .equ WRITE_SYS, 4             # SYSCALL Number for writing to files
  .equ CLOSE, 6                 # SYSCALL Number to close files

  ## * File modes * ##
  .equ READ_MODE, 0              # Reading mode for files
  .equ WRITE_MODE, 03101         # Writing mode for files

  ## * File permissions * ##
  .equ DEFAULT_PERMISSION, 0666  # Default permission to interact with files

  ## * Default file descriptors * ##
  
  .equ STDIN, 0                  # Default GNU/Linux input file
  .equ STDOUT, 1                 # Default GNU/Linux output file
  .equ STDERR, 2                 # Default GNU/Linux error-log file

  ## * Constant variables * ##

  OUTPUT_MSG:                   # "Hello, World!" message
    .ascii "Hello, World!\n"

  SIZE_OF_MSG:                  # Size of "Hello, World!"
    .long 14                    # remember to count '\n' as 1 byte

.section .bss                   # Reserved memory area
  .equ BUFFER_SIZE, 500         # Size of buffer that will be read from STDIN
  .lcomm BUFFER, 500            # Buffer that will be read from STDIN
  

.section .text                  # Code area
.globl _start                   # Starting function definiton



# @brief: Label to terminate program successfuly
_exit_success:
  movl $EXIT_SYS, %eax          
  movl $0, %ebx
  int $LINUX_SYSCALL

# @brief: Label to output `message` that stored in `%ecx`
# @param: `%ecx` must have `message` to output
# @param: `%edx` must have size of `message`
_output_msg:
  movl $WRITE_SYS, %eax
  movl $STDOUT, %ebx
  int $LINUX_SYSCALL
  ret

# @brief: Label to get input `buffer` from STDIN
# @param: `%ecx` must have `buffer` to store data
# @param: `%edx` must have size of `buffer` which will be used for data
_read_msg:
  movl $READ_SYS, %eax
  movl $STDIN, %ebx
  int $LINUX_SYSCALL
  ret


# @brief: Label to get size of a `buffer`
# @param: `%eax` must have pointer to `buffer`'s first char
# @return: size of buffer will be stored in `%edx`
_get_buffer_size:
  movl $0, %edx
  jmp .start_buffer_size
  ret

.start_buffer_size:
  incl %eax
  incl %edx
  cmpl $0, (%eax)   
  jnz .start_buffer_size
  ret

# @brief: _start function to start program
_start:

  ## * Get input message * ##
  movl $BUFFER, %ecx
  movl $BUFFER_SIZE, %edx
  call _read_msg

 
  ## * Output constant message * ##
  movl $OUTPUT_MSG, %ecx        # Store message in %ecx parameter
  movl $SIZE_OF_MSG, %edx       # Store size of message in %edx parameter
  call _output_msg              # Output the constant message

  ## * Output message that was read * ##
  movl $BUFFER, %ecx
  call _get_buffer_size 
  call _output_msg

  jmp _exit_success             # Terminate program
```

#### _exit_success:

This one is to just terminate the program. the `EXITSYS`  is 1, and `LINUX_SYSCALL` is `0x80`.

#### _output_msg:

This label outputs message that is stored in `%ecx`, it's size must be on the register `%edx`. Here `WRITE_SYS` is 4 and `STDOUT` is 1

#### _read_msg:

This label gets input from `STDIN` (which is 0). The `BUFFER` must be stored in `%ecx` and size of  `BUFFER` that is reserved must be on `%edx`

#### _get_buffer_size:

Here `%eax` must be `BUFFER`'s first character, and the output (size of `BUFFER`) will be on `%edx`

I know that `functions` are not used like this in `assembly`, but the method with `stack` was complex for me, so i tried my own method (yes, it's just storing `parameters` and `return value` in `registers`).

***i think*** that the problem is on `_get_buffer_size`, since `segmentation fault` error indicates that a memory address that doesn't exist, or we're not allowed to was accessed (or tried to access) by program.

Comment: Is `_get_buffer_size` supposed to be like `strlen` but in 4-byte chunks?  Or did you mean to check each byte separately with `cmpb` instead of `cmpl`?  And you increment first so it doesn't check the first byte. Also, its caller passes a pointer in ECX, but it's expecting a pointer in EAX.  So that's why it segfaults; GDB should show it.  But really, save the return value from `read`; there's no need to loop over the data unless you're searching for the first or last newline or something.  `read` doesn't zero-terminate the buffer, read / write use pointer+length buffers rather than C strings.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks! I actually forgot that read syscall returns size of message.